# Webpack does not find node_modules when --config flag is used

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack.config.js

I want to use `webpack.config.js` which is outside of my current working directory.
Also this `webpack.config.js` is not in the parent directory of my current working directory it is separated in another location.

In `webpack.config.js` I have requires, like:

```
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
... More requires
```

In my `cmd` I'm positioned to my project directory and when I run Webpack with `--config` flag

```
webpack --config ../path/to/file/webpack.config.js
```

config file is found and used by Webpack but it gives an error that it cannot find circular-dependency-plugin.

It seems that Webpack is searching for the `node_modules` directory in place where `webpack.config.js` is and not in the current working directory.

At least I think that is the case, I might be wrong.

Is there any way I could have Webpack read config file in another location but still use `node_modules` in current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Please check here on how to point to a different directory while resolving modules. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules. In Short

```
const baseDir = process.cwd();
```

and in your webpack.config.js add an entry for

```
modules :[path.resolve(path.relative(baseDir,__dirname),'..path to circular dependency']
```